# Is it possible to generate a Kotlin .def file from a CMake library?

Tags: kotlin, cmake, java-native-interface

I have an existing CMake project which is used to build a native library (supporting a few Linux platforms as well as Windows). This library will soon be integrated into a Kotlin app, for which I need to create a .def file, [as stated here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html)

Conceptually, I could create this using FILE and other native CMake tools, but if there's a "proper" way to do this, I'd prefer to use that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that file something you have to write yourself? I can't tell just from reading the docs, but that's the impression I'm getting. If each `.def` corresponds to a CMake target, you could create a build event custom command by using [the build events signature of `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) to run the `cinterop` command.

If you want to script the process of writing the `.def` file so it's more automatically-robust to you renaming things in the future,

As for putting things like target compile options in a file, you could use the [`$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_GENEX_EVAL) and [`$<TARGET_PROPERTY:>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_PROPERTY) generator expressions and the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) target property and the [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) (and similar) variables in a [`file(GENERATE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate) command call.

Simliar for compile definitions (see the [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) target property).

For a list of all properties supported on targets, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets

Comment: `...so it's more automatically-robust to...`

Yes, this is exactly what I want to do! Theoretically CMake has all the information to generate these handwritten .def files itself, this is a good place to start. Thanks!

Comment: @ijustlovemath I edited to add a list of target properties. you can dig through there for anything else you might need. If you have any other specific needs, edit your question post to clarify what you need and then [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11107541). Maybe I can shed light on anything non-obvious (or maybe not).